# How to exploit open redirect vulnerability which must contain the original url

Tags: web-application, exploit, attacks, url-redirection

Let's say I have the following url: `https://secure.sub.domain.com/?continue=https://sub.domain.com`

I found out that I can put anything I want before `sub.domain.com` in the `continue` parameter as long as `sub.domain.com` is present in that parameter, for example: `?continue=https://google.com-sub.domain.com`.

I tried to bypass this by using a null byte (`?continue=https://google.com%00sub.domain.com`) and a lot of other tricks without success.

Do you have any fresh idea on how to exploit this ?

Answer (score 1):

Get your own domain (I'll use `attacker.com` as an example). Create the subdomain `sub.domain.com.attacker.com`. Setup `sub.domain.com.attacker.com` to redirect to wherever you really want to redirect the user to. Done.

Comment: Or you could end the hostname part with any delimiting character like /,?,#, etc.